# 2D arrays working in Angular JS 1.2.x and not in 1.3.x

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wanted to write a simple loop in Angular for 2D array as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Angular 2D Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var TableCtrl = function($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
          ["val-11", "val-12", "val-13"],
          ["val-21", "val-22", "val-23"]
        ];
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table ng-controller="TableCtrl">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code works fine.

But, if the version of angular used is changed to 1.3.x, I get an error on my browser debug console as:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=TableCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Sb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:19:510)
    at tb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:20:78)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:75:331)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:57:65
    at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at A (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:56:443)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:299)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
```

Do I need to change syntax for my data declaration or is something else that needs to be changed?

Comment: It's not 2D arrays that are not working - it's a global controller function. This is not allowed in 1.3. You need to explicitly register a controller with `.controller("TableCtrl", function TableCtrl($scope){...})`. Also, if you use non-minifed Angular, it will give you more descriptive error messages.

Comment: @RGraham, posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 2D arrays that are not working - it's a global controller function. This is not allowed (by default) in 1.3. You need to explicitly register a `.controller`:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("TableCtrl", function TableCtrl($scope){
  // whatever you currently have
});
```

You also need to explicitly state the app name:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
   ...
</html>
```

(Also, if you use non-minifed Angular, it will give you more descriptive error messages.)

Comment: or opening the url of error will also present the error in nice form :)

Comment: @Mukund, you could override this setting, but I recommend against this. There was a reason Angular team moved away from global functions - it promotes bad practice of defining objects in global scope.

Comment: @NewDev I agree. Being a Java developer I understand to flaws of keeping objects in a global scope rather than a confined modular scope where data is more safe and application more reliable & maintainable

Comment: @A.B, true, but I've seen instances (can't recall now exactly what) where it was more versbose with non-minified than with the url with url-encoded message

Answer (score 1):

As @NewDev suggested, define the controller's on the module.

**OR**

execute `allowGlobals` on `$controllerProvider` in config phase.

[Angular Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-23)

```
angular.module('myModule').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
  // in new ones!
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is about undefined controller. You need to use .controller() to declare controller since you are using angular 1.3

```
var TableCtrl = function($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
          ["val-11", "val-12", "val-13"],
          ["val-21", "val-22", "val-23"]
        ];
      }
```

to

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("TableCtrl",function($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
          ["val-11", "val-12", "val-13"],
          ["val-21", "val-22", "val-23"]
        ];
      })
```

in html:

```
 <html ng-app="app">..........</html>
```